# Im getting E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout and not returning the data, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: android

trying to make a searchview works, with php and mysql.
user enters search query into search view/search bar to search for particular information, the query is sent to php file and result from php file is displayed on RecyclerView.
dont know whats wrong

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView mRVProd;
private AdapterProd mAdapter;

SearchView searchView = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmain, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconified(false);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.clearFocus();
        }
        new AsyncFetch(query).execute();

    }
}

private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    String searchQuery;

    public AsyncFetch(String searchQuery){
        this.searchQuery=searchQuery;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            url = new URL("http://192.168.0.2/prod-search.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                return (result.toString());

            } else {
                return("Erro");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        List<DataProd> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("no rows")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nenhum resultado encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{

            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DataProd prodData = new DataProd();
                    prodData.nomep = json_data.getString("nomeprod");
                    prodData.marcap = json_data.getString("marcaprod");
                    prodData.pesop = json_data.getInt("pesoprod");
                    prodData.valorp = json_data.getInt("valorprod");
                    prodData.pratp = json_data.getInt("pratprod");
                    data.add(prodData);
                }

                mRVProd = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listaprodpreco);
                mAdapter = new AdapterProd(MainActivity.this, data);
                mRVProd.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVProd.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Adapter

```
public class AdapterProd extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<DataProd> data= Collections.emptyList();
DataProd current;
int currentPos=0;

public AdapterProd(Context context, List<DataProd> data){
    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.containerprod, parent, false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

// Bind data
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
    DataProd current=data.get(position);
    myHolder.textnomep.setText(current.nomep);
    myHolder.textmarcap.setText("Marca: " + current.marcap);
    myHolder.textpesop.setText("Peso: " + current.pesop);
    myHolder.textvalorp.setText("Rs " + current.valorp + "\\Und");
    myHolder.textvalorp.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));
    myHolder.textpratp.setText("Prateleira: current.pratprod");

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return data.size();
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView textnomep;
    TextView textmarcap;
    TextView textpesop;
    TextView textvalorp;
    TextView textpratp;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textnomep = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textnomep);
        textmarcap = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textmarcap);
        textpesop = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textpesop);
        textvalorp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textvalorp);
        textpratp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textpratp);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Você clicou em um item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

}

dont know what im doing wrong, keep getting this E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any chance that you are getting an exception while decoding the JSON and go directly to catch block, which skips the adapter initialization?

If you'd like to avoid that I'd suggest you to create an empty adapter set it to the recycler view when the UI initializes(in onCreate() for example), after that just have a method setData(List data) and use it to set the data after the async task finishes. In this case don't forget to call notifyDataSetChanged() when the data changes so that the recycler view is updated with the new data. This way you don't have to recreate the adapter each time you call the service.

PS: For your current code you will get that message each time the UI initializes as it doesn't have adapter attached. You should stop seeing this message once the async task finishes with no exceptions decoding the json.